# How to display the array values in random manner

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray)

iam developing one application.In that i have one array.That contain 5 values 1,2,3,4,5.ANd i want to display that values in random manner.For example first time it display 3 2 4 5 1.And second time 1 3 2 4 5.Like this every time i want to change the order.So please tell me how to do this one.

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047085/reading-random-values-from-an-array, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202102/iphone-nsarray-nsmutablearray-re-arrange-in-random-order

Comment: Please learn to search.  A simple lookup of "random nsarray" would yield you many results.

Comment: use rand(), random() or arc4random() function

Comment: answers are everywhere, just learn to find them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can generate a random number between 0 and array size -1
2. use the number to index the array
3. remove item at the array index

sample code:

```
int i = arc4random() % 4;
NSString value = [arr objectAtIndex: i]
[arr removeObjectAtIndex: i];
```

repeat the steps till you have an empty array.